# Debugging/Finding documentation for new python modules?

Tags: python, debugging, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I'm using VSCode to program in python and in many projects I find very high dependency on google for my project from other people's work which I find very unprofessional and a bad practice.

So I'd like to ask how'd you debug new library classes and find particular function that modify
properties like a widget position, text, value etc...

For example(**You'll need PyQt and PyQtGraph to follow along**) say you wanted to change the position of a simple infinite Horizontal line item to the graphWidget by doing:

```
self.crosshair_h = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
self.addItem(self.crosshair_h, ignoreBounds=True)
```

Already figured the answer (from someone's blog post code)which is:

```
self.crosshair_h.setPos(Y)
```

But still How'd you figure out what command does that?
the intelesense of VSCode doesn't show you anything of it and digging the class definitions of pg.InfiniteLine and pg.PlotWidget by pointing on the class name and pressing CTRL+LEFT_MOUSE which opens the definion file in vscode doesn't contain any setPos() method including in the inherited classes( Same method CTRL+LEFT_MOUSE).

And just searching for the method or class you want to perform on the class in the global search in the documentation doesn't help as it's not mentioned there.

Any suggestion and tips on how'd you do this sort of task your self with less dependency on google?
a Way of searching for such info in a standard documentation in an efficient way would also help(not just searching for the method setPos() in global search of each documentary since this doesn't help in most cases.

Comment: [`setPos()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setPos) is one of the many basic functions of all QGraphicsItems, from which InfiniteLine inherits. You should not only read the documentation of the class you're using, but also always search the documentation for **all** classes it inherits from ("Bases" in pyqtgraph docs): InfiniteLine -> [GraphicsObject](//pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/graphicsobject.html) -> \[[GraphicsItem](//pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/graphicsitem.html), [QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html)].

Comment: Huh nice point I though I guess I got confused while debugging it since when you peek into the line definition it takes you the a re definition file of the py graph library called GraphicsItem.py that inherits "object like that  `class GraphicsItem(object):` I though it overwrites the original Qt file rather then modify and or merge with it.

Comment: It uses multiple inheritance: it extends QGraphicsObject (which is an abstract QGraphicsItem that also inherits from QObject, thus allowing further capabilities like signals) by providing the required implementation that the base class doesn't have (primarily, `boundingRect()` and `paint()`, which are mandatory). All objects that should become part of a QGraphicsScene **must** inherit from QGraphicsItem at some level.

Comment: Well that does answer some questions but still wondering what tools and methods are available for debugging the content of a class including it's inheritance maybe a way to realy read available variables and methods in runtime with the debugger or some thing(I forgot which already but I know python has some functions to show the content of a class and other stuff)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "debug", and what for? I don't use VSCode, but, just like most IDEs, it has its own ways to inspect objects, and should theoretically provide autocompletion (some tweaking might be required for external modules). Besides that, studying the sources is *always* a good thing and an incredibly educational resource. Remember, though, that PyQt is a python binding around the Qt toolkit (which is written in C++).

Comment: I mean get into the definitions of the code deeper like I said before in terms of actually understanding the inheritance tree of objects and available functions and variable of it independently since when you look at the doc of any code almost no matter the size of the organization that released it never covers everything and as a lazy programmer my self I know how not important it feels to not cover everything in the documentation for the users so every other programmer that creates those libraries probably doesn't as well which leaves the individual to understand the code by it's self.

Comment: There are almost always some function that aren't specified in the documentation that are actually critical for the work with the library say in my current example(and I'm not codding that much not in python anyways) in QtGraph there's a function that is called `pg.SignalProxy()` which allows to connect a mouseMove singnal interrupt to a user defined callback function and when you go search for that function the the doc web page you won't be able to see a proper example for it. I eventually managed to find it by like I said having some 3rd party example code pop out of somewhere by shear luck.

Comment: The Qt documentation is generally well written and extremely thorough, and pyqtgraph is normally very similar in this aspect. But you can't expect developers and docs maintainers to provide an example for *every single class or function*. It's also responsibility of the API users to do some "work" on their own.

Comment: Well infact there's nothing written about this function at all like it doesn't exist is the API, and I'm looking for the methods of "the users work" to do that task more effectively.

Comment: Execute `help(pg.SignalProxy)` in the python interactive shell to read its docstring. Also, as said before: 1. read the sources; 2. not all elements of a library should always be fully documented, especially if they're mostly used internally (the fact that Python exposes almost anything is irrelevant); the general purpose of pyqtgraph is their UI/graph API, if you want extended and advanced usage and "know how it works", you must study the sources and how it interfaces with Qt.

Comment: Ok and I'm not into blamming anyone about the documentation that'd acually why I made this post in the first place and asked how'd go around it and study it by your self? what a re the different method and python snippets to do that? that help() if works on enough functions also helps but I'm looking for harder scanning methods for understanding libraries.